# JSON to XML SXLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

Currently, i try to mapping json response from Rocket Chat (RC) webhook to OTRS XSLT.

1. Here what i received from RC.

```html
{
   "_id":"4jA2dgTGzwsHSsiLd",
    "messages":[
      { 
         "username":"guest-3",
         "msg":"youuu",
         "ts":"2018-12-13T15:13:56.906Z", 
      },
      {
         "username":"agent",
         "msg":"hahahaha",
         "ts":"2018-12-13T15:14:06.268Z"
      },
      {
         "username":"agent",
         "msg":"mane tn?",
         "ts":"2018-12-13T15:14:08.817Z"
      },
   ]
}
```

2. and below is my current OTRS XSLT mapping.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="title">
<xsl:value-of select="//type" />
</xsl:variable>
    
<xsl:variable name="custname">
<xsl:value-of select="//visitor/name" />
</xsl:variable>
    
<xsl:variable name="custemail">
<xsl:value-of select="//visitor/email/address" />
</xsl:variable>
    
<xsl:variable name="tn">
<xsl:value-of select="//tags" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="createtime">
<xsl:value-of select="//createdAt" />
</xsl:variable>
    
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RootElement">
       <xsl:copy>
           <TicketNumber><xsl:value-of select="$tn" /></TicketNumber>
           <Article>
               <Body> ? </Body>
               <ContentType>text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15</ContentType>
               <Subject><xsl:value-of select="$title" /></Subject>
               <From><xsl:value-of select="$custemail" /></From>
               <ArticleType>webrequest</ArticleType>
               <SenderType>customer</SenderType>
               <To>Misc</To>
               <HistoryType>AddNote</HistoryType>
               <HistoryComment>Note from RC</HistoryComment>
           </Article>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="content" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to get all the value of messages->username and messages->msg from JSON and pass it to the Body tag. Perhaps like :

Msg: hello world
 By: guest3

Msg: hello there
 By: agent

or maybe html table ?

Thanks ind advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out..
this should be put in  tag

```html
<xsl:for-each select="//messages">
<xsl:value-of select="msg" />
&lt;br/&gt;
<xsl:value-of select="username" />
&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
<xsl:if test="./following-sibling::cd">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```